# Installing fluentd / Kibana / Elastic Search on Suse Enterprise Linux 11

Tags: linux, sles, fluentd

I have successfully installed the recommended `fluentd` stack *( fluentd, Kibana, Elastic Search )* on a Centos 6 virtual machine. But our production environment is all Suse Enterprise Linux 11.

I am trying to work out how to get `fluentd` installed but I am have a hard time with dependencies and other missing pieces. I am trying to use any one of [these quickstart instructions](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/quickstart) and adapt them to my installation but I have just succeeded in breaking my install with incompatible versions of things like `libc.so` when I try and install or upgrade things to where they need to be.

What I really want to do is be able to use the `RPM` installer since Suse Enterprise Linux package manager is based on `RPM` packaging. I know this doesn't work, it broke my system to where I had to re-image it again. But I can't get it to install from source either.

I am an accomplished *Googler* and after 2 solid days of searching and reading and re-building my experimental VM, I am resorting to asking for help.

Here are the details of my environment:

```
wls1:~ # uname -a
Linux wls1 2.6.27.19-5-default #1 SMP 2009-02-28 04:40:21 +0100 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
wls1:~ # cat /etc/SuSE-release
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 0
wls1:~ #
```

*NOTE: If you need any more details or information, please ask in the comments and I will update my question with the additional information!*

Comment: Your link to "these quickstart instructions" seems to be missing. And, also, [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VsBiB.jpg).

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the correct link.

Comment: Your link to the instructions you supoosedly followed _still_ doesn't point to anything that could possibly be what you were doing. Perhaps you should actually explain what you've done so far.

Comment: It points to **all** the various instructions, none of which are really applicable to SEL. I need some help with modifying one of the instruction paths with what to modify for SEL. For example the "from source" link on that page doesn't work on SEL. That is the page I wanted to be linked to. It isn't incorrect, this is the link I intended to post!.

Comment: I have a working fluentd install instructions for a vanilla SLES 11 SP3 VM. They involve deploying build environment and libs from Novell repos and building ruby and fluentd from source (no complications). I can clean these up and post as an answer if you like, however since you are now talking about Kibana init.d scripts, it looks like you are already OK with that part? In which case have you looked at http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/15380.html and/or tried to adapt and existing ruby based init.d script for SUSE/openSUSE?

Comment: @Chainik - please post what you have in whatever condition they are in within the 5 days so I can reward the bounty to someone. I struggled with the `fluentd` build and getting `rubygems` installed; I got it working but I am pretty sure it is more *Redhatty* than *SEL*. I would like to know a more *Suseish* way of doing it. I am setting this up in a VM to hand over to a DevOps team and I don't want it rejected for some silly reason that I could avoid before hand. Ultimately I want a Chef/Puppet script but I have to get all the pieces first.

Comment: You propably have to update to SP3 first. Your SuSE-relase shows the EoL SLES11 without any SP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is a procedure I used to install fluentd (from source) starting from a minimal SLES 11 SP3 install in a VirtualBox VM.  It is based on [this](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/install-from-source) guide.

(1) download SLE-11-SP3-SDK-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso (Product: SUSE Linux Enterprise Software Development Kit 11 SP3) from [Novell](http://download.novell.com/index.jsp) and install using these [instructions](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/esd/ii_sle_11_sdk_sp2.html)

```
$ yast
select Software -> Add-On Products
mount and select DVD1 of the SDK you downloaded from above
install with defaults
```

Note: this adds SDK repositories, which allow instillation of git, openssl-devel, etc., witch are required to build from source

(2) install build environment (compilers, make, etc.)

```
$ install -t pattern Basis-Devel
```

(3) install dependencies

```
$ zypper install git-core
$ zypper install openssl-devel
```

(4) download and build ruby from source (the version in the Novell repos is not suitable for fluentd)

```
$ mkdir -p /opt/install
$ cd /opt/install
$ curl http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz > ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz
$ tar -xvf ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz
$ cd ruby-2.0.0-p247
$ ./configure
$ ./make install
```

(5) build and install fluentd

```
$ cd /opt
$ git clone https://github.com/fluent/fluentd.git
$ cd fluentd/
$ gem install bundler
$ rake build
$ gem install pkg/fluentd-0.10.39.gem
$ fluentd --setup ./fluent
$ fluentd -c ./fluent/fluent.conf -vv &
```

(6) test fluentd

```
# test
$ echo '{"json":"message"}' | fluent-cat debug.test
```

(7) create start-up scripts using Novell's template or a number of other SUSE/ruby init scripts you can find on the Web.

Try running this on your test VM first, but it should work as I've just done it and it worked for me without errors.

-- ab1